# Photoshop how to zoom in center of picture/text?

Tags: image, text, zooming, center, photoshop

I lost my text in CS6 Photoshop. I have no clue where it went - all I know is that it went off canvas. How can I zoom in dead center on that piece of text?

I realize I could just delete it and restart, but knowing how to will help for pictures I'd work on in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a programming question and is more suited to other forums.

However, if you loose text or part of a layer as described above, just zoom out (to something small like 5%) and then press CTRL + T (free transform), this will allow you to see the transform box of the text. You'll be able to move the text back from the canvas from there.